# Getting a clean copy from the remote repository using git

Tags: git

I'm using git with an SVN repository. My local 'master' branch is a little messed up and every time i do a `git svn rebase` I end up in all sorts of issues, which neither me or the guys I work with can fix. So is there a way I get just get a clean copy from the remote repository which will just overwrite all the changes in my local branch.

Comment: I guess we'll need more details to be able to help you. The first step would be that instead of `git svn rebase` you do the two things it does separately. First, do `git svn fetch` and than do `git rebase trunk`. See which fails and how and tell us.

Answer (score 6):

Reset will change all your tracked files into your remote repository

```
git reset --hard
```

Clean -xdf will also clear all your untracked files in your repository

```
git clean -xdf
```

This will help you to make a "whole" clean repository.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. That didn't work the way I expected. Actually, it didn't work. It clearly did something, but not what I wanted. I just want to get all the files and commits in the remote SVN repository to replace my current local git repository. A kind of 'update my local main repository with everything and don't ask me any questions. Just overwrite it' 

The problem is it keeps going into rebase area where it tells me there are locks on the files. I remove the locks, add the changes, update git and then the same thing happens. I'm still quite a noob to git.

Comment: @screenm0nkey: It's a problem somewhere else. If you don't have any local changes (`git log trunk..` shows nothing), than the problem is in the fetch from svn, not your local changes. Reset indeed won't fix those.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean:

```
git reset --hard trunk
```

That will make current branch point at specified revision (reset with revision) and worktree match (`--hard`). Your previous version remains in reflog until `git gc` 90 (configurable) days later.

Note, that the name of `trunk` might be different as it depends on your particular setup (I have `svn/trunk`, but I believe I've defined the `svn/` prefix when initializing git-svn).

Comment: See the comment on Kits post as you both have posted the same thing. I think;)

Comment: @screenm0nkey: We posted **significantly different** things. I posted `git reset --hard SOMETHING` (`trunk` is the default name of the branch tracking subversion trunk, though it may be configured differently), while he posted just `git reset --hard`. Just `git reset --hard` only discards _uncommitted_ changes, which I am sure is not enough for you. You need the parameter (and need to check your config for whether `trunk` will do or what name you need).